# Управление железом, создание робота

Tags: железо, робототехника

Вот недавно увидел презентацию робота, и стало очень интересно, как можно здесь так-же... Хочу спросить как управляется робот с помощью компьютера? Какой язык нужно выучить чтобы можно было сделать хоть и примитивного робота дома? Трудно ли это всё потом прикрутить к самому роботу(написанную программу)? Извините за явные ляпы в тексте, просто я ещё этим никогда не занимался... И есть ли хорошие книги по этому?

P.S Есть опыт в PHP, но думаю он для этих целей не очень подходит.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте для начала [Lego Mindstorms](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) - в него встроен небольшой типа SDK - некая визуальная среда программирования роботов. Можно делать довольно сложные штучки.

Для более сложных вещей попробуйте [Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/robotics/)

Comment: дорого и глупо, лего этот так совсем для детей

Comment: А как же взрослые дядьки, которые собирают из лего 3D принтеры в гараже? Их оскорбляет ваше пренебрежительное отношение к лего.

Comment: из лего 3d принтер? а вырезает он каким образом? мне просто подарили как-то этот Lego Mindstorms, разочаровал он меня как программиста, тем более стоит он в районе 10т.р. за эти деньги можно в 10 раз больше более высокоточных компонентов для ардуино подобного контроллера купить т.ч. на мой взгляд выбор очевиден.

Comment: К нему туча разного железа производится. А "голова" поддерживает по-моему до 8 портов с возможностью расширения. Плюс недавно узнал, что есть JVM для Lego - так что можно программировать на Java.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от задач, для начала можно освоить http://arduino.ru и соответственно его Си-подобный язык. У нас правда готовые блоки дорогие, т.ч. лучше с Китая заказывать напрямую. P.S. До робота так и не дорос, но вот вай-фай чайник смонстрячил, пользы особо никакой конечно, но зато гостей можно поудивлять :)